# Multiple StreamBuilder inside ListView failed to listen to the same Stream

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart, bloc

I have 2 `StreamBuilder` inside `ListView` that listen to the same `Stream`, that is `valueStream`. Inside that `StreamBuilder`, I have `SwitchListTile` that add new value to `valueStream`.

This is my `Stream`:

```
Observable<bool> get valueStream => valueController.stream;
```

This is my `ListView`:

```
ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
        Switch1(key: UniqueKey(),),
        Switch2(key: UniqueKey(),),
    ],
),
```

This is `Switch1` widget:

```
class Switch1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Switch1(
      {@required Key key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Switch1State createState() => _Switch1State();
}

class _Switch1State extends State<Switch1> {
  DummyBloc _dummyBloc;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      stream: _dummyBloc.valueStream,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
        print('rebuild Switch1');
        if(!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
        return SwitchListTile(
          value: snapshot.data,
          onChanged: _dummyBloc.updateValue,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _dummyBloc = DummyBloc();
  }
}
```

This is `Switch2` widget:

```
class Switch2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Switch2(
      {@required Key key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Switch2State createState() => _Switch2State();
}

class _Switch2State extends State<Switch2> {
  DummyBloc _dummyBloc;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      stream: _dummyBloc.valueStream,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
        print('rebuild Switch2');
        if(!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
        return SwitchListTile(
          activeColor: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
          value: snapshot.data,
          onChanged: _dummyBloc.updateValue,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _dummyBloc = DummyBloc();
  }
}
```

If I touch the `Switch1` widget, the `StreamBuilder` inside `Switch2` supposedly rebuild, and vice versa, but that didn't happen. I tried to add `UniqueKey` to `Switch1` and `Switch2`, but that doesn't help. Any suggestion how to make this work?

Comment: Each switch has its own instance of DummyBloc when I think you'd want them to share the same DummyBloc object.

Comment: You are not listening to the same stream , instead you are listening to different instance of streams in both widgets because you are creating new instance of bloc in the widget and just a disclaimer do not create instances in the didChangeDependecies()

Comment: Whoops, you're right, this is how I suppose to create the dummyBloc
_dummyBloc = BlocProvider.of(context).dummyBloc;
Where do you think I have to create DummyBloc inside the Widget? I use this repo as my reference to my BLOC pattern: https://github.com/shiang/flutter-form-with-validation-BLOC